# Angular JSON Parse error from Promise Return

Tags: angular, promise

I am trying to get a name from a promise I wrote and I can hit the API with postman and in my network tab I can see see the request but in console, I am getting a parse error.

My Component looks like

```
  generateAppointments(companyID): any {

    this.appointments = null;
    this.appointmentService.getAppointmentsByCompanyID(companyID).then(r => {
      console.log(r);
      this.appointments = r;
      this.appointments.forEach((item, index) => {
        let customerName = this.getCustomerNameByID(item.customerID);
        console.log(customerName);
        let newAppointment = {
          id: item.appointmentID,
          description: item.appointmentNotes,
          subject: customerName,
          //calendar: this.getCustomerNameByID(item.customerID),
          observCat: item.customerID,
          observSub: item.observationCategoryID,
          start: new Date(item.appointmentDate),
          end: new Date(item.appointmentEndDate),
        }
        this.scheduler.addAppointment(newAppointment);
      });
    });
    //console.log(this.source);

  };
```

which calls

```
  getCustomerNameByID(customerID) {
    this.appointmentService.getCustomerNameByCustomerID(customerID)
      .then(data => { this.customerName = data; return data; }).catch(err => 
      console.log(err));

  }
```

The Service promise looks like:

```
  getCustomerNameByCustomerID(customerID): Promise<string> {
    return this.httpClient.get<string>(this.baseUrl + 
     'api/Appointments/GetCustomerNameByCustomerID?CustomerID=' + customerID)
      .toPromise()
      .then((res) => { console.log(res); return res; });
  }
}
```

My chrome console error is:

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:5000/vendor.js:7509:51)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:5000/polyfills.js:2768:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:5000/vendor.js:48600:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:5000/polyfills.js:2767:60)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:5000/polyfills.js:2540:47)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:5000/polyfills.js:2843:34)
    at invokeTask (http://localhost:5000/polyfills.js:4089:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:5000/polyfills.js:4126:21)"
```

The text that it gets back and tries to parse is `"Smith,Benjamin 0014662"` I don't know why it is trying to parse JSON, I just want to get that value back.

I am trying to set that value in the newAppointment variable but it is asking for `subject:` to be a string but complains it is void, which I believe is unrelated but not sure.

I am new to angular so I am not extremely familiar with all this. The endpoint returns what I want it to but I am not sure why it thinks that the result needs to be parsed from JSON.

**EDIT** I have a console.log(customerName) which returns unspecified. Like I said, the API returns: `"Smith,Benjamin 0014662"` but my TS is not getting that value and instead complaining of a parse error.

Comment: use this
.then(res => res.text())          // convert to plain text
  .then(text => console.log(text))

Comment: https://daveceddia.com/unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that API is returning a text body you could do the following.

```
getCustomerNameByCustomerID(customerID): Promise<string> {
  return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + 
    'api/Appointments/GetCustomerNameByCustomerID?CustomerID=' + customerID, { responseType: 'text' })
    .toPromise()
    .then((res) => { console.log(res); return res; });
}
```

FYI: By default the HttpClient tries to parse the response into a JSON object unless specified otherwise. Adding responseType as `text` will tell HttpClient to expect the response as a string and not parse it.

Comment: So this got rid of the console error with the parse but my console now shows undefined from the console.log in the component which is right after I call the service from the component. The console.log from the service is showing the right information. Like I said, the parse error is gone. Any ideas on why my promise is undefined.

Comment: EDIT: I assume it is because the promise is asynchronous. What can I do to make this all work?

Comment: your method `getCustomerNameByID` isn't returning anything. Ideally your `getCustomerNameByID` should be returning the promise returned from from `getCustomerNameByCustomerID` method in the service. All the logic about creating new appointment should be moved into the resolved callback of `getCustomerNameByID` method. Basically just make sure you are  understanding how to work with asynchronous methods.

Comment: @AndyPet74 if the given solution answered your question, can you mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

first check your returning json it hapens when json syntax error and if its not the case declare aponments as array

```
let appointments =[];
```

Comment: When you say, "returning json" are talking about from my service? The service I thought was just returning a string, but my TS when calling the server complains about JSON not being parsable.

Comment: yes your service if that returning string convert to json first

Comment: So I was trying to do that, do I use `JSON.parse(res)`? That is what I Was trying but it was not doing anything differently.

Comment: add this JSON.stringify(data) check this